# django invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'game_count'

Tags: python, django

I am making simple application by django that the counters go up one by one if user click button. When I ran following code, then it displays the error message "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'game_count'" what is the cause of this problem?

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    game_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User
from .forms import CountForm

def user(request):
    form = CountForm(request.POST or None)
    game_count = User.objects.get(game_count='game_count')

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
       game_count += 1
       game_count.save()

    return render(request, 'app/user.html', {'count':game_count})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class CountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("game_count",)
```

user.html

```
<p>{{ count }}</p>
<form action="" method="POST">
<button type="submit">go</button>
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your

```
game_count = User.objects.get(game_count='game_count')
```

line.
As per your model **game_count** is an integer field but you filter its values by a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It now worked referred your advice and then by making some modifications to this.  However, as new problems have arisen again, I will ask it as another topic.